# Uninstall a Package From Angular Project

Tags: angular, uninstallation, owl-carousel

I installed a Package of Owl carousel in My project,Now I need to remove it from my Project.
How it is possible, i tried ng uninstall but it not worked

Comment: You can uninstall packages using a package manager. Like In npm, you can use `npm uninstall <package-name>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the commands:

> `npm uninstall <name>` removes the module from node_modules, but not
>   package.json
>
> `npm uninstall <name> --save` also removes it from dependencies in
>   package.json
>
> `npm uninstall <name> --save-dev` also removes it from devDependencies
>   in package.json
>
> `npm -g uninstall <name> --save` also removes it globally

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
npm uninstall owl.carousel
```

or

```
npm u owl.carousel
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular will keep a track of all the packages that you have installed using **package.json** file.

There will be a dependencies object inside package.json file which maintains all the packages or dependencies that are being used by the application.

You can remove  **owl.carousel** package from your dependencies inside package.json and then do `npm update` which removes the package from your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your `package.json` file, there you will see `"owl.carousel": "^x.x.x"`, just remove that line and delete your **node_modules** using `rm -rf node_modules`. 
After doing so, do `npm install`. 
This is will remove your Owl carousel from your project.